# Reclassify raster values with GDAL

Tags: python, reclassify

I would like to reclassify a raster with the following code:

```
#RBR reclassification to USGS burn severity values

arr = np.array(RBR_MultiplyBy1000_Int)

level1 = (arr >= -500) & (arr <= -251) #-2 Enhanced Regrowth, high (post-fire)
level2 = (arr >= -250) & (arr <= -101) #-1 Enhanced Regrowth, low (post-fire)
level3 = (arr >= -100) & (arr <= 99) #0 Unburned
level4 = (arr >= 100) & (arr <= 269) #1 Low Severity
level5 = (arr >= 270) & (arr <= 439) #2 Moderate-low Severity
level6 = (arr >= 440) & (arr <= 659) #3 Moderate-high Severity
level7 = (arr >= 660) & (arr <= 1300) #4 High Severity

levels = [level2, level3, level4, level5, level6, level7]
reclass_values = [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

RBR_reclassed_arr = np.where(level1,-2, arr)
for level, val in zip(levels, reclass_values):
  RBR_reclassed_arr = np.where(level, val, RBR_reclassed_arr)
```

But when the reclassification is finished, I get the following raster values:

[image]

It seems to me that some values are not reclassified because I have the min value of -650, normally should be -2 the min value.

Comment: What is `RBR_MultiplyBy1000_Int`

Comment: Is my raster array with integer raster cell values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this should be posted as comment rather than answer because your question is not really clear, but let me try (sadly I have no privilege to add comments yet):

1) I do assume that your question is related to numpy rather than gdal

2) Assuming that you have -650 as minimal value in your raster (which from our point of view is numpy variable called arr) - there is no level which contains values as low as -650 (level 1 reassigns values starting from -500 and higher), so it remains unclassified

Corrected code would look like this:

```
import numpy as np

#fake data as we don't have access to your raster/array
arr=np.array([[-650,-400,200],[300,500,900]]) 

level1 = (arr >= -650) & (arr <= -251) #-2 Enhanced Regrowth, high (post-fire)
#level1 changed to include -650

level2 = (arr >= -250) & (arr <= -101) #-1 Enhanced Regrowth, low (post-fire)
level3 = (arr >= -100) & (arr <= 99) #0 Unburned
level4 = (arr >= 100) & (arr <= 269) #1 Low Severity
level5 = (arr >= 270) & (arr <= 439) #2 Moderate-low Severity
level6 = (arr >= 440) & (arr <= 659) #3 Moderate-high Severity
level7 = (arr >= 660) & (arr <= 1300) #4 High Severity


#levels adjusted, so they contain level1.
#this is not strictly problem in previous version of code, but better for clarity
levels = [level1, level2, level3, level4, level5, level6, level7]
#reclass values also adjusted    
reclass_values = [-2,-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

RBR_reclassed_arr = arr
for level, val in zip(levels, reclass_values):
    RBR_reclassed_arr = np.where(level, val, RBR_reclassed_arr)
```

Output:

```
array([[-2, -2,  1],
       [ 2,  3,  4]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. Really, the problem was with the outlier values that were not included in the first class. I strictly implemented the USGS recommended classification and this led me into trouble.